# convert search field input to url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

Let's say I need a simple search form:

```
<form action="<%= search_path %>" methode="GET">
  <input type="text" placeholder="where?" name="place_name" />
</form>
```

I need to generate a url based on the input field so I can show:

```
/search/some-value
```

I tried:

```
match 'search(/:place_name)', to: 'some_controller#some_action', as: 'search'
```

Any suggestions why it's not working or what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you submit a form, the parameters set via inputs within the form will be appended to the URL using query parameters — in your case that would look something like this:

```
/search?place_name=some-value
```

That’s the basic form behavior and there’s no easy way around this unless you want to use some Javascript to handle the request (which I would advice against in this case).

To use the default behavior however, your route would need to look like this:

```
match 'search', to: 'some_controller#some_action', as: 'search'
```

The parameter `place_name` will then be available in the controller using:

```
params[:place_name]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: so no easy way doing it except of javascript or another redirect?

Comment: I'm afraid so. -- May I ask why you feel you need this URL format?

Comment: I see. That's done with JS. Turn it off and it falls back to a basic query: `https://www.airbnb.com/s?location=berlin&checkin=&checkout=&guests=1&submit_location=Search&page=1`

Answer (score 0):

The following code supports unicode and additional parameters:

```ruby
get "search/*place_name" => "store#search"
get "search" => redirect {|_, req| 
  params = req.query_parameters
  query = Rack::Utils.escape params.delete(:place_name){"%"}
  "/search/#{query}#{params.to_query.prepend('?') if params.any?}"
}, as: :search
```